# Problem approaching this proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $h: R^n \rightarrow R$ be a $C^1$ function. Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ be a compact convex set. We have to prove that there exists $C \geq 0$ such that for every $x, y \in S$
$$|h(x) - h(y)| \leq C||x-y||$$
Im supposed to use MVT and EVT to solve this but the issue is that MVT requires an open set and $S$ isn't an open set so im not sure how to approach it. Also where would be a starting point for this proof? The assumptions i have are

1. $S$ is a convex set so
   $$\text{For every} x,y \in S, \forall t \in [0,1], tx + (1 - t)y \in S$$
2. S is a compact set so it is closed and bounded
3. $h$ is a differentiable function and its derivative is continuous since its a $C^1$ function.

EDIT: is there a workaround for using MVT on a closed set?

Comment: Two hints: a) a continuous function on a compact achieves its (finite) maximum and minimum, b) Because of convexity, you can apply MVT to the restriction of your function to any segment between points in the domain, so for any two points you can get a bound on $|f(a)-f(b)|$.

Comment: @GReyes in other words apply MVT on the domain $t \in (0,1)$?

Comment: Exactly. For the restriction $f(x(t))$ where $x(t)$ is the parametrization of the segment, $t\in[0,1]$.